# Header redirection doesn't work in some browsers

Tags: php, header, redirect

I'm using this command to redirect to another page:

```
header('Location: \dealer\skuska\layout.php');
```

In Chrome this works correctly, but in Firefox it is redirecting to:

```
http://212.5.221.26:85/dealer/skuska/actions/\dealer\skuska\index.php
```

Why is that happening, and how could I fix it?

Comment: according to [rfc2616 protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30), it should be absolute URI. relative works but it will be inconsistent as you have seen.

Comment: Please check slashes vs backslashes. Paths are suppost to have slashes i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use full path like this

```
header('Location: http://example.com/dealer/skuska/layout.php');
```

also change `\` to `/`

try this, this will work in all browsers.

Comment: Yes, this works. But what if someone will migrate site to another server? Is  it possible to use any global variables here?

Comment: in you config define constant like.. define("CONSTANT", "http://example.com"); or use $_SERVER object to get current domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Just use absolute url, then regardless where you call it, it will redirect you to the correct page. Chrome is less restrictive as to web standards, therefore allows for such inappropriate url. Also use forward slashes in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this redirect-script is located in "dealer/skuska/actions/", try using forward slashes, and add a two-dot directory to navigate one folder up, to redirect to "dealer/skuska/layout.php":

```
header('Location: ./../layout.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-use website, then use the absolute url. The whole url the landing page has.

If you need it to run on multiple domains, then use ../../../ till you reach the root folder, then add the full path again.

And use slashes, not backslashes